# Javascript Alert message showing twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a program that on button click pops an alert message. Whenever the message pops up and I click OK, the message pops up again. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Here is my code:

```
If MyDataTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then

    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Order # does not exist!');</script>")

Else

    Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Order updated!');</script>")

    OrderTextEditor.Text = ""
    TypeTextEditor.Text = ""

End If
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Don't write directly to the response. Make use of [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: In which event is that code located?

Comment: In an UpdateOrders() that is called on button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
Dim myScript As String = "window.alert('There is a problem');"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myScript", myScript, True)
```